React-native gradlew assemblerelease failed miserably
My project was running without any problem. Suddenly it all went wrong. The thermal printer part started malfunctioning and further assemblerelease also become impossible.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\BINEESH\Documents\Software_Projects\react-native\printer\android\settings.gradle' line: 6

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.



Could not get unknown property 'com' for settings 'android' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date
